# How to block cherry-pick to a specific branch on gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a branch where I want to restrict commits depending on an attribute from a bug tracking tool. So I have setup a check in the ref-update hook to do it when the change is pushed from git. But when someone cherry-picks a change from another branch and there are no conflicts changes get in without checking for the attribute.

1. Is there a way I can check for this attribute from gerrit too?  (or)
2. Can I block cherry-picking on gerrit for certain branches only?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can block a specific commit or to lock a branch. 
If you want to block a cherry-pick you will be able to do so like this:

Use a hook (pre-receive) for example.
Then check the list of desired commits and find out if any of then is already in the repository and if you find it - decide if to keep it or not.

***The problem:***
What will happen in a merge and push? assuming all the commits are already in the repository and you are trying to merge them. Based upon the commit detection it will be blocked.

The hook which handle the merge is a client side hook while the hook which handle the push is a server side hook.

**Summary:**
You can block a certain commit on a selected (or all) branches if you know its SHA-1, otherwise you will have to find a way to know that a commit is a cherry-pick commit.

Comment: Thanks @CodeWizard for the answer. Gerrit doesn't support git hooks so using pre-receive isn't an option. I am not sure which gerrit hook to use. Will see if I can use the patchset-created gerrit hook. Will update if I am successful. I am wondering if anyone knows what actually happens when you choose "cherry-pick" on the UI. That might help.

Comment: When you use cherry-pick it simply take the commit and add it to your branch as the latest commit